# Is it inefficient to use RecyclerView's Nested Adapters?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[image]

Hi, I'm working on a little complicated `dynamic recyclerview` right now.

To explain, there is an `item` in `MainRecyclerView` like the picture.

This `Mainitem` is `dynamically added/deleted` whenever the button is clicked.

And as you can see from the picture, the `Mainitem` has a `SubRecyclerView` inside it again.

`SubRecyclerview` is also `added/removed dynamically` through the button in the photo.

At least as a beginner, I think that to implement this, there must be an `Adapter` for `MainRecyclerView` and an `Adapter` for `SubRecyclerView` inside it.

But I think I've seen somewhere that these `nested Adapters` are difficult to implement and inefficient.

What do you think?

Is there any better way? Or a library for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested `RecyclerView's` are fine if implemented in right way.
Performance improvement of `RecyclerView's` in general could be done using:

- `RecyclerView caching,`
- `GPU rendering optimisation`,
- `RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool`,
- `RecyclerView prefetch`

And, Most important thing is that `RecyclerView` doing his job -> recycling views.

Additional content that might help you to improve RecyclerView performance:

**Gpu Rendering** -> https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering

**Slow rendering** -> https://developer.android.com/topic/performance

If you don't know what is causing performance issue, then try isolated metod by testing part by part manually. Eg. If you have 10 `ViewHolders`, start measuring performance  with first one by disabling all other `ViewHolders`, then try to increase `ViewHolders` types in adapters and measure again.